# How to Create a Duration picker in Material Angular in Angular 8

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I am looking to implement a duration which can capture input in HH:MM format. The mat-datepicker can be option but limitation will be it will allow to capture time within 24 hours, But the input field should also be able to capture input like 32:45 which is 34hrs and 45mins.

I am not sure if we can achieve with datetime picker. Capturing with mat-input field alone will also be a great.

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-label>Enter the Duration</mat-label>
 <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
 <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have designed a Directive for the DurationPicker which can be applied to the Mat-input field

Demo in the below link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lyajg3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-duration-picker-directive.ts